# Why is useEffect hook not calling functions in first render?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

`readTodos()` is a redux action creator which fetches Todo Items from `localstorage` and stores them in a redux state(`globalstate`). I want to call the `readTodos()` function in `useEffect` function and update `globalstate` variable which will display all `TodoItems` in `ViewTodos` component in the first render. However, the `readTodos()` action is not getting called when the component loads and the list in return function is not getting populated.

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import {  useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { actionCreators,State } from "../../state/state";
import { TodoInterface } from "./interfaces";
import {  Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import "../styles/createTodoStyles.css"

export const ViewTodos =():JSX.Element =>{
   //REDUX starts here
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {readTodos} =bindActionCreators(actionCreators,dispatch);
  const globalstate = useSelector((state:State) => state.todo)

   useEffect(()=>{
    readTodos();
   },[]);
    
    return(
        <Container>
          <Row>
              <h1>Todo List</h1><ul>
        {
          globalstate.Inprogress.map(Element =>{
            return (
              <li> {Element.Title} </li>
            )
          })
        }
        </ul>
          </Row>
          
        </Container>
    )
}
```

`readTodos()` action creator code:

```
export const readTodos = () =>{

    var mystorage = window.localStorage;
    var Completed = JSON.parse(mystorage.getItem("completed")|| "[]");
    var Inprogress = JSON.parse(mystorage.getItem("inprogress")|| "[]");

    var todolist={
        Completed:Completed,
        Inprogress:Inprogress
    }

    return (dispatch:Dispatch) =>{
        dispatch({
            type:"readTodo",
            payload:todolist
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that `readTodos()` is actually not getting called by putting a  `console.log()` inside the function? By the react lifecycle, `useEffect` is getting called after the component mounts.

Comment: I just tried it and it's getting called on the first render. My redux state variable( globalstate) is also getting updated, however, my Todos list is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your redux action is async, so even though it gets kicked off on initial render, that data hasn't been loaded into the redux store by the end of that render.  I would suggest checking to make sure `globalState.Inprogress` exists (or has a length greater than zero, depending on your use case) before trying to map over it.

```js
return (
  <Container>
    <Row>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
      <ul>
        {globalstate.Inprogress && // or globalstate.Inprogress.length > 0 &&
          globalstate.Inprogress.map(Element =>{
            return (
              <li> {Element.Title} </li>
            )
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </Row>
  </Container>
)
```

Comment: Are operations on local storage async in nature or the redux dispatch async in itself? I've updated the code in the description. 
I tried checking if globalState.Inprogress exists or not but it didn't work for me.